# Adding Elastic IP causes shell login to fail

Tags: amazon-ec2

After *associating* Elastic IP on a Cloud server instance I cannot login anymore

```
ssh -i "ec2.pem" ubuntu@1.2.3.4
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is...
Please contact your system administrator.
```

How can I asssign a static IP (Elastic IP) with my EC2 Cloud server and still be able to login with the system / console?

Comment: Are you logging in with the private IP from another machine at AWS, or with the public IP or with an DNS name?

Comment: Using the Elastic IP example: ssh -i "ec2.pem" ubuntu@{ELASTIC_IP}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is merely a warning that you are connecting to a system that had a different SSH fingerprint, as stored in your local `.ssh/known_hosts` file. If you know things are okay, just delete the appropriate entry from that file and you can connect again.

Comment: ssh-keygen -f "/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 1.2.3.4